# Least Square Estimator in terms of residuals

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, linear-model

Given the following problem:

Suppose the data vector $Y$ satisfied the model $$Y=X\beta+\epsilon.$$
Here $X=(X_1 ,X_2) $ is an $n\times k$ matrix, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $n \times k_1$ and $ n \times k_2$, respectively, with $k_1+k_2 = k$; $\beta = (\beta_1, \beta_2)^T$ is $k \times 1$ where $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are non zero $k_1\times 1$ and $k_2\times 1$ vectors, respectively; $\epsilon \stackrel{iid} {\sim} N(0, \sigma^2)$; all matrices are full rank. Suppose we omit $X_2$ and estimate $\beta_1$ using the model: $$Y=X_1\beta_1 + e^*$$ using least squares. Denote this estimate by $\tilde{\beta_1}$.

The question if to express the LSE and SSE for $\beta_2$ under the full model in terms of $R=Y- X_1\beta_1$, the residuals of the reduced model, and $X_2$.

I know that the LSE of $\beta$ in the full model is $(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$, but I am not sure how to rewrite this expression so that I get the LSE of $\beta_2$ in terms of $R \text{ and } X_2$.

I'm hoping that if I see how to write the LSE of $\beta$ in terms of $R \text{ and } X_2$ I will be able to write SSE in terms of $R \text{ and } X_2$ on my own.

Comment: Is this a study exercise? If so, please add the self-study tag and have a look at its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)